# Get a single object from a Room query in a background thread and use it in the view. Android/Kotlin/MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In my current solution to this I use coroutines and return a `MutableLiveData` in the `ViewModel` that the view .kt class observes.

DAO function:

```
@Query(
    "SELECT workout_name FROM workout_table " +
        "WHERE id = :workoutId"
)
suspend fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): String
```

Repository function:

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): String {
    return database.workoutDao().getWorkoutName(workoutId)
}
```

ViewModel function:

```
fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): MutableLiveData<String> {
    val workoutName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        workoutName.postValue(repository.getWorkoutName(workoutId))
    }
    return workoutName
}
```

View .kt function:

```
private fun setUpAppBar() {
    binding?.apply {
        viewModel.getWorkoutName(currentWorkoutId!!).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            editWorkoutTopAppbar.title = it
        }
    }
}
```

This works but I think there's a better way of doing this. My main problem is in the `ViewModel` because I'm making a `MutableLiveData` variable, returning it to the view and giving it a value when ready.

Two other ways I've seen is returning `LiveData` from the DAO and repository functions and having the view observe it, but this way I think the database query is not done in a background thread. Another way is having the view .kt file launch the coroutine but I believe the view is not supposed to launch coroutines.

The ViewModel using a coroutine when repository returns LiveData:

```
fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): LiveData<String> {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        return repository.getWorkoutName(workoutId)
    }
}
```

The above code gives me an error because I'm returning the result from inside a coroutine.

Please let me know a solution, or maybe if I'm approaching this problem the wrong way.

Comment: You can return `LiveData` instead of `MutableLiveData`: 
`fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): LiveData<String>`

Comment: You can also return `LiveData<String>` from your DAO so you don't have to do any extra work.

Comment: @MFazio23 Can you expand on this answer, maybe give a code example. My question with this method is that I don't know if I can do the Room query on a background thread using coroutines (as I've said at the bottom of my post).

Comment: @MFazio23 I'll updatge my post with a code example of the viewModel when the reposotory function returns LiveData<String>

Answer (score 1):

First, it's better to use `viewModelScope` instead of creating new coroutines scope since `viewModelScope` cancels itself if the veiwModel gets destroyed. secondly, you need to expose a LiveData to fragment or activity instead of MutableLiveData because LiveData can not be manipulated from outside.

so your viewModel should look something like this:

```
private val _workoutName = MutableLiveData<String>()
val workoutName : LiveData<String>() get() = _workoutName


fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _workoutName.postValue(repository.getWorkoutName(workoutId))
    }
}
```

Comment: I will take your advise on using viewModelScope but the code will be cleaner If I keep the liveData variables in the function since its specific to one thing.

Comment: Maybe my solution is returning `LiveData<String>` from the DAO function because this might do the query in the background by default, but I have to look more into it. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#livedata

Comment: You can use `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {...}` since `launch` takes a dispatcher as well.